# Custom Facebook like for facebook pages eg:https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create the facebook like functionality to LIKE the page using facebook graph api's rather then javascript embeds given by fb.

I can like posts using api : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/$object_id/likes

object_id for bbcnews is `228735667216`

but when i am using the same thing for pages it is giving error as

```
 {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3
  }
```

I also tried with actions via `og.likes` but cannot like that bbc url.

Please help me
 
1.is it even possible to do?
2. where i am going wrong? i.e the object_id or url ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am sorry, what are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to "Like" the page by making the call to the above mentioned url or you're trying to fetch some data?

Comment: trying to LIke the page

Comment: I don't think its possible. Its also mentioned in the official documentation any user cannot like any page via api. Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes#publish

Comment: Thanks man, well then i can stop searching and move on